# Yii : hide items of radioButtonList

Tags: php, yii, radiobuttonlist

In Yii I have form which contains radioButtonList as follows:

```
<?php echo  $form->radioButtonList($model, 'send_option', array('mobile'=>'Send SMS to Mobile','email'=>'Send an E-mail')); ?>
```

I an very newbie to Yii. I wanna hide the second item (i.e. Send an E-mail) of the list.

Any suggetions are appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you trying to hide the item with Javascript (client-side) or server-side (PHP)?  If you don't want "Send an E-mail" to appear, you could just remove it from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove this by Yii clientScript. Something like below

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
    $('#ModelClassName_send_option_1').hide(); 
    //If your model class name is Message (eg) then it should be $('#Message_send_option_1').hide();
    $('label[for=\"ModelClassName_send_option_1\"]').hide();
");
```

Or you can remove it from array. simply

```
<?php echo  $form->radioButtonList($model, 'send_option', array('mobile'=>'Send SMS to Mobile',)); ?>
```

Comment: in the view i want to hide it. on a button click i check whether the user has an email or not. If s/he has an email then I want to show the email option

Comment: here wht is 'search'?

Comment: search is script name.

Comment: If you want to hide by button click then put your hiding scripts under button click event: Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
    $('#button_id').click(function(){
        if(/*mail ckeck*/){
            $('#ModelClassName_send_option_1').hide();
            $('label[for=\"ModelClassName_send_option_1\"]').hide();
        }
    });
");

Comment: no.It's normally hidden. When the user clicks on a button the system will check if there is an email for this user. If it is, then the email option will be appeared. What I want is, email option will appear on the button click.

Comment: My model -> $model = new User;

Comment: Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
    $('#User_send_option_1').hide();
    $('label[for=\"User_send_option_1\"]').hide();
    $('#button_id').click(function(){
        if(/*mail exiting condition*/){
            $('#User_send_option_1').show();
            $('label[for=\"User_send_option_1\"]').show();
        }
    });
");